# Import makefile-based C project into an IDE

Tags: c, makefile, intellisense

Is there a way to import a makefile-based C project into an IDE?

I want to use IntelliSense, code browsing and other advanced features available in IDEs, so any IDE that has those will do.

Comment: This likely belongs on programmers.SE . Flagging.

Comment: Hm, in the [FAQ] it says that you can ask about "Coding techniques" and "Software development tools". Are you sure you're not mistaken?

Comment: Certainly. There are many questions that _could_ fit in multiple SE sites, hence you should choose the one that fits a question the best.

Comment: OK, but in programmers.se [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/about), it says "Don't ask" about "Coding techniques" and "Software development tools". So wouldn't that make it a worse fit for my question?

Comment: At this point I must admit that I am slightly unsure, although I do feel that the question falls under `development methodologies` from http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NetBeans](https://cnd.netbeans.org/cnd-tutorial.html#CreateMakefileProject) has the ability to import a C project based on an existing Makefile.  It has most of the features you'd expect from an IDE.

Just go to `File->New Project` and select `C/C++ Project with Existing Makefile`

I use the feature all the time and it seems pretty reliable.

[Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/getting_started/cdt_w_import.htm) lets you import an existing project too but it's a little more work.

Comment: I tried netbeans, and it worked great, thanks. Eclipse didn't work, some declarations weren't recognized, netbeans works better here it seems.